# SMTP Error <<: 503 AUTH command used when not advertised

Tags: email, authentication, exim, exim4

I am facing this error in Webmail Lite.

I have Exim installed. Here is a snippet of the auth block:
    PLAIN:

```
  driver                     = plaintext

  server_set_id              = $auth2

  server_prompts             = :
  .ifndef AUTH_SERVER_ALLOW_NOTLS_PASSWORDS
  server_advertise_condition = ${if eq{$tls_cipher}{}{}{*}}
  .endif 

  server_condition           = “${if crypteq{$auth3}{${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$auth2}lsearch{/etc/$domain/passwd}{$value}{*:*}}}}}{1}{0}}”
```

I have the passwd stored in the following format:
username:{MD5}asddfasdlasdkandlanskfdaf

How do I get AUTH enabled and working ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information. From your description it is not clear what your situation is, what you are trying to do and what is the actual problem.

Comment: The same problem has already been asked and answered here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/313562/exim-configuration-503-auth-command-used-when-not-advertised

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this error message is sending HELO instead of EHLO, or sending EHLO in the wrong order.

But this message can occur even if EHLO is used, when the server is running Exim.

On my server, I found the solution. In WHM > Home > Service Configuration > Exim
Configuration Manager, the option "Require clients to connect with SSL
or issue the STARTTLS command before they are allowed to authenticate
with the server" was set to the default (On). I'm not sure if I did this
or not, and it is ordinarily a great idea for security, but forces the
mailserver to enable (advertise) only the STARTTLS command, not AUTH. So
when my script sends AUTH, the error message the server sends is correct.
Further information is at http://blog.networkpresence.co/?p=8923 .
Someday when I have time I will find out how to change my script to use
TLS, so I can turn that Exim option On for security.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,this error not coming regularly.some time it works but some time it gives this error.(SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.)

I debug this then I found this

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "503 AUTH command used when not advertised "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "503 AUTH command used when not advertised "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:503 AUTH command used when not advertised
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: 503 AUTH command used when not advertised
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```